# Vue.js template concatenate props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

JS:

```
Vue.component('profile', {
    template: `<a v-bind:href="id"></a>`,

    props: ['id']
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '.app',
    data: {
        user: userobject
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<profile :id="user.id"></profile>
```

Expected result:

```
<a href="/profile/2">
```

Question:
How to concatenate `"/profile/"` with `user.id` that is equal to 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write javascript inline in Vue templates like this:

```
template: `<a v-bind:href="'/profile/' + id"></a>`,
```

---

Alternately, you could bind to a computed property:

```
Vue.component('profile', {
  template: `<a v-bind:href="url"></a>`,
  props: ['id'],
  computed: {
    url() {
      return '/profile/' + this.id;
    }
  }
});
```